# Thanks to Aaronut for his years of service!

Tags: discussion, moderators

[Aaronut](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/41/aaronut?tab=profile) was appointed as a pro tem moderator in 2010, then elected as a moderator in 2011 in [our very first moderator election](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/election/1). Unfortunately he hasn't been active on the site in the last year, and it's policy to remove inactive moderators, so his moderator status was removed today.

Over the years he contributed a great deal to the site, both as a moderator and as a user on [the main site](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/41/aaronut?tab=topactivity) and [here on meta](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/users/41/aaronut?tab=topactivity). He has the third highest reputation on the site, and on meta he has by far the most answers of any user. He helped keep the site running smoothly, he helped iron out the scope and policies of our site from the beginning, and he shared an awful lot of cooking knowledge.

So, Aaronut, on behalf of the other mods and the community you served, thanks for everything you did!

Comment: It's policy to remove inactive moderators? Where do you see such a policy? The only thing I've ever found is Jeff Atwoods comments in his "A Theory of Moderation". Curious, thanks!

Comment: @dpollitt It's part of the job description for being a moderator that you lead the community and dedicate a couple hours a week to moderating the site. If you're not doing anything and haven't been seen in months, you're not doing that. We don't really need or want a publicly stated policy of "this happens at *x* activity" because it's not that straight forward, there are exceptions, and how much activity we expect can vary depending on the site.

Comment: @animuson - Thanks for the info. That makes sense. On another SE site we ran into the issue of not being able to find a policy, so we weren't really sure what action was appropriate. If a policy did exist, I was interested in that. Anyways thanks!

Comment: I hope he's OK. It's kind of worrisome to see someone drop off the face of the internet like this, with no previous drama to account for things.

Comment: @Marti I'm concerned too, but I'm a bit less concerned than I would otherwise be because he gradually reduced his time here for months before he disappeared.